# How to Prevent User from using Fake Email to Login into Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I'm developing an app that uses firebase to login user. The problem I'm having is that user can create account using fake email and still login into my app. I tried to use sendEmailValification() in my CreateAccountActivity to send user vilification message but to no avail since user can still login with the fake email.

```
   **Expectations**
```

**1:** I want the user to create an account first in CreateAccountActivity using verifiable email. after verifying user email then login the user by clicking the createAccount button. If the Email can't be verify don't login.

**2:** Registered users can login through LoginActivity using their verified Email and Password by clicking the login button.

**3:** unverified or fake email entered during account registration should not be seen in my firebase Authentication and real-time database.

**NB:** To avoid duplication of question, I have searched to know if I can find any similar problem but to no avail so I will be glad if someone can help me with the answer or provide a link that will help me solve my problem.
And finally I'm new in firebase so please while trying to solve my problem don't assume anything lol, just remember that you're explaining to a novice.

Here is my CreateAccountActivity.java

```
public class CreateAccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
// valuable declaration for CreateAccountActivity.XML views
    private EditText First_Name, Last_Name, Email_Address, Login_Password, Age;
    private Button Btn_Create_Account;
    // FirebaseAuth declaration 
    private FirebaseAuth auth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_account_activity);

//valuable initialization
        Email_Address = findViewById(R.id.EtEmail);
        Login_Password = findViewById(R.id.EtPassword);
        First_Name = findViewById(R.id.EtFirstName);
        Last_Name = findViewById(R.id.EtLastName);
        age = findViewById(R.id.EtAge);
        Btn_Create_Account = findViewById(R.id.ButtonCreateAccount);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        Btn_Create_Account.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        RegisterUser();

    }

    private void RegisterUser() {
// Getting EditTexts values

        final String FirstName = First_Name.getText().toString().trim();
        final String LastName = Last_Name.getText().toString().trim();
        final String Email = Email_Address.getText().toString().trim();
        final String Password = Login_Password.getText().toString().trim();
        final String Age = age.getText().toString().trim();
        if(FirstName.isEmpty()){
            First_Name.setError("First name is required");
            First_Name.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(LastName.isEmpty()){
            Last_Name.setError("Last name is required");
            Last_Name.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(Email.isEmpty()){
            Email_Address.setError("Email is required");
            Email_Address.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

// right email patterns must be use
        
if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(Email).matches()){
            Email_Address.setError("Invalid Email address");
            Email_Address.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(Password.isEmpty()){
            Login_Password.setError("Password is required");
            Login_Password.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(Password.length() < 6){
            Login_Password.setError("Password is too short");
            Login_Password.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(Age.isEmpty()){
            age.setError("Age is required");
            Age.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
// Firebase Authentication, authenticating user
     auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
// if authentication is successful create user database with user infor
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        userDetails user = new userDetails(FirstName, FirstName, Email, Password, Age);

                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
// Login to ProfileActivity if user database is created

 if (task.isSuccessful()) {                                                                                                
startActivity(new Intent(CreateAccount.this, ProfileActivity.class));                                     
finish();                                                                                                                                                                                } 
 
// show Toast when database is not created

else{                                                              
Toast.makeText(CreateAccount.this, "Unable to connect try again: " + task.getException().getMessage(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }

// show Toast when Authentication failed

                else{
                    Toast.makeText(CreateAccount.this, "Unable to connect: " + task.getException().getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my LoginActivity.Java

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
// valuable declaration

    EditText Email_Address, Login_Password;
    Button Btn_Login;
   
    FirebaseAuth auth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_activity);

// Getting view Id

        Email_Address = findViewById(R.id.EtEmail);
        Login_Password = findViewById(R.id.EtPassword);
        Btn_Login = findViewById(R.id.ButtonLogin);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        Btn_Login.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.ButtonLogin:
                LoginUser();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void LoginUser() {

// getting EditTexts values

        String Email = Email_Address.getText().toString().trim();
        String Password = Login_Password.getText().toString().trim();

// EditTexts validations

        if(Email.isEmpty()){
            Email_Address.setError("Email is required");
            Email_Address.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(Email).matches()){
            Email_Address.setError("Invalid Email address");
            Email_Address.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(Password.isEmpty()){
            Login_Password.setError("Password is required");
            Login_Password.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(Password.length() < 6){
            Login_Password.setError("Password is too short");
            Login_Password.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
// after validation login user
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
// if login is successful open ProfileActivity 
              
if(task.isSuccessful()){                  
                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
// if login is not successful show Toast message
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Registration failed try again: " ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How user can login through fake mail? You can check either the mail is verified or not.

Comment: A user can create fake email address say user@gmail.com which he/she can't have access to and still login. That's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `auth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified()` to check whether the email is verified or not in `LoginActivity` below `if(task.isSuccessful())`

To send verification mail to user's mail, kindly have a look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth#kotlin+ktx_1).

Comment: I don't want email verification in LoginActivity, I want user to login once the user have valid email address since the email must have been verified during registration of User account in CreateAccountActivity.

Comment: @Neldison I'd consider this a valid answer, while I'd not consider "I want to" a valid argument. The misconception may be, that having added a user would be the same as letting the user login with these credentials already, while they've not validated them. It's built alike this, so that one could have it both ways, as required.

Comment: @Neldison In Create account activity code I couldn't see the code to send verification mail and to check either it is verified of not using the code mentioned in answer. Follow this link to see documentation for the same  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth#kotlin+ktx_1